# Tessnet2 in WebForms .Net returns DllNotFoundException liblept172.dll

Tags: c#, .net, webforms, tessnet2

I wrote a basic app using Tessnet2 and now trying to move it to a WebForms website.

Copied the logic etc. but when I run it I get an error message(Exception: DllNotFoundException)

```
"An exception of type System.DllNotFoundException" occured in Tesseract.dll but was not handled in user code.
Additional information: Failed to find library "liblept172.dll" for platform x86."
```

As said above, this code works as a C# console and after applying necessary logic to move it to the website I thought I moved everything correctly but keep getting this error. Any thoughts where to look?

EDIT2:

Digged it out a bit deeper and the part that fails is actually ILibraryLoaderLogic

```
IntPtr LoadLibrary(string fileName);
```

Even if the file is actually there?
(there appears to be platform difference in what

```
SystemManager.GetPlatformName();
```

returns as the console runs under x64 but website under x86)

Answer (score 2):

Obviously quite long after the fact, but in my situation it turns out the machine I deployed to didn't have the VS2015 x86 & x64 runtimes installed. 
The runtimes are dependencies as described here: https://recordnotfound.com/tesseract-charlesw-26531

Answer (score 0):

Another issue that can appear is that the respective libs are not set to copy to the Output Directory. The way I solved it was by changing the "Copy to Output Directory" setting for the x86/x64 libs to "Copy always/if newer", then everything worked as expected